# Doubling the array size in C?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

So I have a this piece of C code:

```
void main (void){

int i,n,r,*pt1;
printf("Enter array size:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
srand(time(NULL));
char niz[n];
pt1=niz;
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    r=rand() % (15);
    printf("%d\n",r);
    if (r==0)
        break;
   niz[i]=r;
    if (i==n){
        pt1=(char*)realloc(niz,(sizeof(n)*2));
        if (pt1==NULL)
        printf("Jbg");
    }

}

free(pt1);
return 0;
```

}

Now the point here is when the counter comes to the end in the loop, to double the array size. Is the code with pt1 OK? Also, I'm getting segmentation fault at the end of the printf, and I'm not sure why.
Thanks in advance!! :)

EDIT:
Thanks to everyone for your answers, this is my revised & functional code:

```
void dupla(int n){ 

int i,r;
srand(time(NULL));
char * niz=malloc(n);
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    r=rand() % (15);
    printf("%d\n",r);
        if (r==0)
            break;
niz[i]=r;
        if (i==n){
            niz=(char*)realloc(niz,n*2);
        }
}
if (niz==NULL)
            printf("Jbg");
        else
            printf("It works\n");
            printf("%d",sizeof(niz));
free(niz);
}


void main (void){

int n;
printf("Enter array size:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
dupla(n);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of `realloc`.

Comment: `char niz[n];` — this isn't pure C. And if `n` would be large you'll get troubles.

Comment: @Eddy_Em it is legal C actually (but remark about keeping it small holds)

Comment: But this construction will allocate memory in stack. `realloc` allocates dynamic memory.

Answer (score 6):

You must only use `realloc` on a pointer that was obtained by a call to `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`. Your code doesn't do that, so it is broken.

It should probably be like this:

```
char * niz = malloc(n);

// ...

char * tmp = realloc(niz, n * 2);

if (tmp) { niz = tmp; }
else     { /* flagrant error */ }

// ...

free(niz);
```

Comment: (In C++, you could write `if (char * tmp = std::realloc(nix, n * 2)) { niz = tmp; }` and avoid leaking `tmp` into the ambient scope. Maybe one day C will also allow this syntax.)

Answer (score 3):

`realloc` says for its first parameter

> Pointer to a memory block previously allocated with malloc, calloc or realloc, or a null pointer (to allocate a new block).

`niz` is on the stack so you will have undefined behaviour.  You should allocate `niz` using `malloc` initially.

Answer (score 2):

You can not realloc array allocated in stack. You should've started with allocating it in heap. Also, your initial array is `char[]` and pt1 is `int*`, which makes it a bit unclear what your intention is.

Comment: better to say statically allocated and dynamically allocated.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, no, stack allocations can often be seen as dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* pt1 = malloc(n);
for (i=0; i < n + 1; i++) { // 1 more than the elements for the if.
    r = rand() % (15);
    printf("%d\n",r);
    if (r == 0)
        break;
    pt1[i] = r;
    if (i == n) { // Past end of array.
        n *= 2;
        --i; // So in the next loop i == old n.
        pt1 = (char*)realloc(pt1, n)); // n * sizeof(char)
        if (pt1 == NULL) {
            printf("Jbg");
            break;
        }
    }
}
free(pt1);
```